# Extract and set key with Kafka Connect SpoolDir Json SourceConnector

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to configure the SpoolDir source connector to read some nd-json files from a directory. The files have a structure like this:

```
{"key": "myKey1", "value": ["myValue1", "myValue2"]}
{"key": "myKey2", "value": ["myValue3", "myValue4"]}
{"key": "myKey3", "value": "myValue2"}
```

It seems that there is no documented way to extract the key from the json.
Firstly I tried with the SchemalessJson connector and it works with the official basic configuration in the example, but all the keys in the Kafka Topic are null.
So I configured the connector using transforms, but I got an error saying that it expects a Struct but got String.

```
name=SchemaLessJsonSpoolDir
tasks.max=1
connector.class=com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirSchemaLessJsonSourceConnector
input.path=/home/spooldirTest/json_input
input.file.pattern=^.*\.ndjson$
error.path=/home/spooldirTest/json_errors
finished.path=/home/spooldirTest/json_output
halt.on.error=false
topic=spooldir-schemaless-json-topic
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
transforms=extractKey,extractValue
transforms.extractKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.extractKey.fields=key
transforms.extractValue.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value
transforms.extractValue.field=value
```

Is there a way to make transforms working with the schemaless connector?
Meanwhile, now I'm trying to configure the connector version with schema and `schema.generation.enabled=true` but the autogenerated schema doesn't work as expected and all the value are null. It's not documented how to pass the schema in the connector config properties. Does it need an AVRO, a Json Schema?

Thank You!

Comment: Doesn't this connector read the entire line as the Kafka record value? It doesn't parse the lines

Comment: Yes, the Schemaless version doesn't parse the lines. That's why I was trying to understand how to configure correctly the schema version. Basically, I need the connector to read and set also the key for each record. I can also change the structure of the input files if needed.